# does onblur support multiple if else statements?

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="0"    id="x1" onblur="ThisEvent()"/>x1</br>               
    <input type="text" value="0"    id="x2">x2      </br>

<script>
    var x1      = document.getElementById("x1");    
    var x2      = document.getElementById("x2");

function ThisEvent(){
    if (x1=1)   {x2.value--;}else{
    if (x1=2)   {x2.value++;}else{
    if (x1=3)   {x2.value+0;}}}
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

seems to only fire the first if statement and ignore the else situation. any help would greatly be appreciated

Comment: Mistaken Boolean you have made it like assignment. i.e it should be `if (x1==1)`

Answer (score 1):

`=` is an assignment operator.

`==` & `===` are comparison operators. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/5743988) for the difference between them)

It's stopping on the first `if` statement because `x1=1` returns `1`, which is truthy.

Once you switch to using comparison operators, you should be using `x1.value == 1` to compare the numerical value of the `<input>`, or you could use `x1.value === "1"`.

Comment: i have attempted to put == for all three if situations and it doesnt fire at all

Comment: same with === and same results

Comment: @bretsimonson You forgot to use `.value`.

Comment: i did forget to use . value in the conditional of the if statement. works like a charm thank you Barmar

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="0"id="x1" onblur="ThisEvent()">x1     </br>   
    <input type="text" value="0"    id="x2"     >   x2      </br>
<script>
    var x1      = document.getElementById("x1");    
    var x2      = document.getElementById("x2");

function ThisEvent(){// needs a lot of work done to it
    if (x1.value==1)    {x2.value--;}else{
    if (x1.value==2)    {x2.value++;}else{
    if (x1.value==3)    {x2.value+0;}}}}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: much appreciated 4castle and Barmar